# Cannot set "startingDay" to day

Tags: typescript, datepicker, ng2-bootstrap

I am trying to set the `startingDay` to 1 resp. to monday. The way I try this is:

```
public dateOptions:any = {
  startingDay: 1
};
```

For some reason it does not work. Did I miss something or why does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, angular2 uses typescript on top of es2015(javascript). 
All javascript is valid typescript but when using typescript syntax you stay with it until the end and respect the guidelines.

Because i saw that dateOptions is of type ":any" (where types is a feature of typescript) in you example I'm able to say that your error is on how you tried to assign a default value to startingDay.

```
class Foo {
    public dateOptions:any = {
       startingDay:number = 1
    };
}

var a = new Foo();
alert(a.dateOptions.startingDay);
```

you can try it here https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html by copying the code above and pasting on the left side and then by clicking run on the top right corner.

Comment: That any does not come from my code, I just tried it out in the ng bootstrap demo page (I haven't changed anything). That is why I do not get it why it does not work. But I will have a look at your Example.

Comment: if you want to set startingDay to 1 you must use = instead of :   If it doesn't solve your problem then put the link to the source

Comment: Your aproach does not work with the demo code, so I will just link you the source.
I cloned this project and tried to play around with the demo project -> datepicker. [Ng2 Bootsrap](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap)